# Unlocking asp.net mvc templates in VS 2008

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Ok so i downloaded the asp.net mvc through the web platform installer. Rebooted the machine and fired up VS 2008 express. Lo and behold there were no website/project templates that could setup an mvc project. I did a little research and found out they would not show up in the express version. No matter - i got team suite edition too so i installed that and hoped for the templates to show up. They did not, so i reinstalled the mvc and they still won't show up.

I hate this part of developing - i just want to dognammed tools to work - what am i doing wrong - why won't the templates show up? I can't seem to uninstall mvc now and reinstalling just tells me that it's already installed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed Team Suite *after* mvc, it won't see the templates. Try reinstalling MVC, it's light and shouldn't take long.

Comment: How do i reinstall mvc? I just tells me it's already installed - there is no repair option and no remove as far as i can see?

Comment: Ok my mistake - i found it under add/remove programs, i must be tired - i'm sure i looked before and found nothing

Comment: The other alternative is to just download the MVC install package from http://www.asp.net/mvc. It is about 2MB if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have asp.net mvc installed and don't see templates in visual studio, you should try to run administrative command prompt and run devenv - setup so that templates can be registered.

c:\Windows\system32>cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE"

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE>devenv - setup

this should help

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? I thought that but it HAS to be .NET 3.5 AND it's a Web Application from the New Project dialog and not through the New Website dialog. Annoying but alas!